# SwiftUI Custom Camera View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-camera

I'm playing with SwiftUI and trying to build a custom camera with it. I found tutorials on how to use system built-in camera with SwiftUI(using ImagePickerController) and how to build a custom camera with storyboard.
I've already built a `struct CameraViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable` that initialize the camera and setup capturesession.(using AVFoundation).
First I'm not sure how to setup `func makeUIViewController` for `CameraViewController` struct, since I dont know which controller class to conform to.
Also I don't know how to integrate my CameraViewController class into the app with SwiftUI. Can someone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't really understand why someone rated the question down. Is it because it's impossible to implement custom camera interface with SwiftUI or is it just too "dumb" of a question?

Comment: I don't understand neither why your question has been downvoted

Comment: I have been trying to find the solution for sometime now, but I could only find AVCam application on apple developer forum which uses storyboard and UIKit. Please let me know if anyone of you found an answer to this question.

Comment: SwiftUI has moved away from Interface Builder and Storyboard. Check out the answer and note `ZStack`, `VStack`, `HStack` etc as opposed to `IBOutlet`

Answer (score 41):

## SwiftUI - Custom Camera Implementation Example

1. CustomCameraPhotoView     / Main Screen - Photo Preview

   2. CustomCameraView          / Camera Screen - Combines SwiftUI View (Record Button) with UIKit ViewController

   3. CustomCameraRepresentable / Custom Camera ViewController SwiftUI Wrapper

   4. CustomCameraController    / Custom Camera View Controller

   5. CaptureButtonView         / SwiftUI View - Capture Button

**Note**: Avoid app crashing by adding this `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` into the Info.plist file.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
 
struct CustomCameraPhotoView: View {
    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var showingCustomCamera = false
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.secondary)
                    
                    if image != nil
                    {
                        image?
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Text("Take Photo").foregroundColor(.white).font(.headline)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.showingCustomCamera = true
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingCustomCamera, onDismiss: loadImage) {
                CustomCameraView(image: self.$inputImage)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
        }
        
    }
    func loadImage() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }
        image = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
    }
}


struct CustomCameraView: View {
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @State var didTapCapture: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            
            CustomCameraRepresentable(image: self.$image, didTapCapture: $didTapCapture)
            CaptureButtonView().onTapGesture {
                self.didTapCapture = true
            }
        }
    }
    
}


struct CustomCameraRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var didTapCapture: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CustomCameraController {
        let controller = CustomCameraController()
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ cameraViewController: CustomCameraController, context: Context) {
        
        if(self.didTapCapture) {
            cameraViewController.didTapRecord()
        }
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
        let parent: CustomCameraRepresentable
        
        init(_ parent: CustomCameraRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
            
            parent.didTapCapture = false
            
            if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
                parent.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}

class CustomCameraController: UIViewController {
    
    var image: UIImage?
    
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    
    //DELEGATE
    var delegate: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate?
    
    func didTapRecord() {
        
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: delegate!)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }
    func setup() {
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
    }
    func setupCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }
    
    func setupDevice() {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera],
                                                                      mediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                                      position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
        for device in deviceDiscoverySession.devices {
            
            switch device.position {
            case AVCaptureDevice.Position.front:
                self.frontCamera = device
            case AVCaptureDevice.Position.back:
                self.backCamera = device
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        
        self.currentCamera = self.backCamera
    }
    
    
    func setupInputOutput() {
        do {
            
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
    func setupPreviewLayer()
    {
        self.cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
        
    }
    func startRunningCaptureSession(){
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}


struct CaptureButtonView: View {
    @State private var animationAmount: CGFloat = 1
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "video").font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(30)
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.red)
                    .scaleEffect(animationAmount)
                    .opacity(Double(2 - animationAmount))
                    .animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 1)
                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
        )
            .onAppear
            {
                self.animationAmount = 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this post when I was looking for help on using AVFoundation in SwiftUI. This worked like a charm.

Comment: Hello @ozmpai.  Your code works great for capturing still images. I was trying to get frame by frame data in my project using AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate. Can you suggest modifications to the above code you posted? Thanks.

Comment: Stumbled across this through google and it works perfectly, thanks! However, is there any way to get the View to be smaller to fit in the corner of the screen? I can't seem to change the size of it.

Comment: @indra have you got your answer? i'm also looking for same.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version, where you can pass any frame size for camera preview layer.

If you have a back button, ozmpai answer does not work out of the box. I have edited ozmpai answer, so all kudos still goes to him.

Don't like the shared singleton, but for now, haven't figured a better approach for adaptation of SwiftUI view lifecycle yet. As SwiftUI is probably using black magic behind it.

Also, passing a bool to take a photo is probably not the greatest approach, so I have refactored it with a closure.

```
import SwiftUI
 
struct MyCameraView: View {
    @State private var image: UIImage?
    
    var customCameraRepresentable = CustomCameraRepresentable(
        cameraFrame: .zero,
        imageCompletion: { _ in }
    )
    
    var body: some View {        
        CustomCameraView(
            customCameraRepresentable: customCameraRepresentable,
            imageCompletion: { newImage in
                self.image = newImage
            }
        )
        .onAppear {
            customCameraRepresentable.startRunningCaptureSession()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            customCameraRepresentable.stopRunningCaptureSession()
        }
        
        if let image = image {
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
    }
}



import SwiftUI

struct CustomCameraView: View {
    var customCameraRepresentable: CustomCameraRepresentable
    var imageCompletion: ((UIImage) -> Void)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height - 100)
                cameraView(frame: frame)
                
                HStack {
                    CameraControlsView(captureButtonAction: { [weak customCameraRepresentable] in
                        customCameraRepresentable?.takePhoto()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func cameraView(frame: CGRect) -> CustomCameraRepresentable {
        customCameraRepresentable.cameraFrame = frame
        customCameraRepresentable.imageCompletion = imageCompletion
        return customCameraRepresentable
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct CameraControlsView: View {
    var captureButtonAction: (() -> Void)
    
    var body: some View {
        CaptureButtonView()
            .onTapGesture {
                captureButtonAction()
            }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct CaptureButtonView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    @State private var animationAmount: CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "camera")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(20)
            .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.black)
            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .stroke(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.black)
                    .scaleEffect(animationAmount)
                    .opacity(Double(2 - animationAmount))
                    .animation(
                        Animation.easeOut(duration: 1)
                            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
                    )
            )
            .onAppear {
                animationAmount = 2
            }
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

final class CustomCameraController: UIViewController {
    static let shared = CustomCameraController()
    
    private var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    private var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    private var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    private var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    private var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    
    weak var captureDelegate: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }
    
    func configurePreviewLayer(with frame: CGRect) {
        let cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

        cameraPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        cameraPreviewLayer.frame = frame
        
        view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer, at: 0)
    }
    
    func startRunningCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
    
    func stopRunningCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        
    }
    
    func takePhoto() {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        
        guard let delegate = captureDelegate else {
            print("delegate nil")
            return
        }
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: delegate)
    }
    
    // MARK: Private
    
    private func setup() {
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
    }
    
    private func setupCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }
    
    private func setupDevice() {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
            deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera],
            mediaType: .video,
            position: .unspecified
        )
        
        for device in deviceDiscoverySession.devices {
            switch device.position {
            case AVCaptureDevice.Position.front:
                frontCamera = device
            case AVCaptureDevice.Position.back:
                backCamera = device
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        
        self.currentCamera = self.backCamera
    }
    
    private func setupInputOutput() {
        do {
            guard let currentCamera = currentCamera else { return }
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera)
            
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray(
                [AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.hevc])],
                completionHandler: nil
            )
            
            guard let photoOutput = photoOutput else { return }
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomCameraRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
//    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    init(cameraFrame: CGRect, imageCompletion: @escaping ((UIImage) -> Void)) {
        self.cameraFrame = cameraFrame
        self.imageCompletion = imageCompletion
    }
    
    @State var cameraFrame: CGRect
    @State var imageCompletion: ((UIImage) -> Void)
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CustomCameraController {
        CustomCameraController.shared.configurePreviewLayer(with: cameraFrame)
        CustomCameraController.shared.captureDelegate = context.coordinator
        return CustomCameraController.shared
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ cameraViewController: CustomCameraController, context: Context) {}
    
    func takePhoto() {
        CustomCameraController.shared.takePhoto()
    }
    
    func startRunningCaptureSession() {
        CustomCameraController.shared.startRunningCaptureSession()
    }
    
    func stopRunningCaptureSession() {
        CustomCameraController.shared.stopRunningCaptureSession()
    }
}

extension CustomCameraRepresentable {
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
        private let parent: CustomCameraRepresentable
        
        init(_ parent: CustomCameraRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                         didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto,
                         error: Error?) {
            if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
                guard let newImage = UIImage(data: imageData) else { return }
                parent.imageCompletion(newImage)
            }
//            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Working like a charm!

Comment: Crashing on Xcode 14, iOS16.

Comment: Fixed it, CustomCameraRepresentable should be a struct and all the vars should be @State vars. See if that works.